# TextAnalysisTool.NET equivalent for OS X

Tags: macos, search, regex, logging

I've used [TextAnalysisTool.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20150829071422/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/delay/archive/2007/06/21/powerful-log-file-analysis-for-everyone-releasing-textanalysistool-net.aspx) in the past for analyzing log files on Windows machines and found it incredibly useful. I love the simplicity+power that it achieves for dynamically grepping log files, saving profiles, colorizing output, and hiding unmatched lines.

I've tried [LogrPro](https://web.archive.org/web/20131208110350/https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/logrpro/id698893878?mt=12) and was underwhelmed. I've also tried running TextAnalysisTool.NET under Mono without success. Are there any alternatives out there that work on OS X?

Comment: Thanks for being so polite to me, Neil. Good luck with your future searches. It matters little, of course, that Splunk is distributed free for the SOHO market.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae can you explain how Splunk solves my problem. You give me a link to a tool that looks like an enterprise level logging solution with zero explanation. I'll be happy to try it with some pointers. Otherwise, I don't see the connection to TextAnalysisTool. Something targeted at analyzing user logs in the 100K-10MB range offering multiple ways to parse, filter and analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question almost 10 years later thanks to this [hackernews comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=39084887); the tool is called [Klogg](https://github.com/variar/klogg):

> [Klogg](https://github.com/variar/klogg) is a multi-platform GUI application that helps browse and search through long and complex log files. It is designed with programmers and system administrators in mind and can be seen as a graphical, interactive combination of grep, less, and tail.